# SQL - Is it possible that only part of my stored procedure was execute in case of connection issues?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example I have this stored procedure(**There is no Begin Tran and Commit**)

```
DECLARE @ID1 int
DECLARE @ID2 int

--Let's say this insert takes 1 second.
INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2)
VALUES('test', 1)

--And this insert takes another second.
INSERT INTO table2 (field1,field2)
VALUES ('testing', 2)
```

What would have happened if the SQL Server would go down after 1.5 second because of a power outage(Real Story).

Comment: Is there any COMMIT at the end of the procedure?

Comment: Both are likely to execute, If you disconnect from server doesn't mean that SQL server is down and not accessible. Try to check with DBCC Opentran as test

Comment: @twyly there is no Commit and no rollback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute your stored procedure in a `transaction` :

```
begin tran
   exec sp
commit
```

and the client disconnects while executing it, the whole work done by your sp will be rolled back.

If you call your proc not from a transaction and the client disconnects between one `insert` and another, the `insert` that was finished will not be affected, the `insert` that was executing while disconnecting will be rolled back.

REPRO:

```
create table dbo.table1 (id int);
go

create proc dbo.sp_test
as
--Let's say this insert takes 1 second.
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 
VALUES( 1)
waitfor delay '00:05:00'
--And this insert takes another second.
INSERT INTO dbo.table1
VALUES ( 2)
go


--open new query window and write there:
begin tran
   exec dbo.sp_test;
commit;

-- wait for some seconds; close this window
-- now check for what was inserted:

select *
from dbo.table1;
---
-- nothing was inserted


--open new query window and write there:

   exec dbo.sp_test;

-- wait for some seconds; close this window
-- now check for what was inserted:

select *
from dbo.table1;
---
--1
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, is there a way to reproduce this scenario?

Comment: Yes of course. Just add waitfor delay '00:05:00' between your inserts, this way your code will wait fo 5 minutes after the first insert, and close SSMS query window from where you execute your sp after some seconds, executing your proc from transaction/without explicit transaction, then check the table what was inserted

Comment: Thx, is it possible to define in db level that all stored procedure should act like they have Begin Tran Rollback or do I need to do it manually?